# Embed Word document preview in WinForms app

Tags: winforms, ms-word

How can I embed a word document in a form or usercontrol like the explorer preview panel does?

I found [this topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/127bd801-525d-41c3-8516-cac7c68ec43b) and they say DSOFramer isn't available any more, but what should I use now? A third party tool is only acceptable if its free.

The only thing I noticed was that prevhost.exe starts a winword.exe process with the -Embedding command switch, but I can't find any information on this switch.

Comment: -Embedding is used to start an out-of-process COM server. That's not what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found the solution, it was kinda obvious. I created a UserControl which accesses the [IPreviewHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from word like the windows explorer does and host the preview in my control. The CLSID I use is {84F66100-FF7C-4fb4-B0C0-02CD7FB668FE}

You can use the Windows 7 API Code Pack for the interface declarations. I don't know if its offical supported by microsoft but for me it did the job.