# How to embed ms word into winform

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to know the ways of embedding ms word with limited controls in winform . and also i want to insert some headers and footers in to the ms word. Found some articles which depicts only embedding the controls inside the winform . So my question is how to generate a document file and limit the controls of msword inside the winform . Anyone help me.

Comment: do you 100% need word or rich text box would also be enough? see here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15585/Building-a-Simple-Word-Processor-Around-an-Extende Personally I would use the DevExpress RichText Editor: http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796994/embed-word-document-preview-in-winforms-app

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply . But i need to draw tables on some cases . Is it possible on Rich Text Box

Comment: It really depends on what sort of rich text box you use. Search for "Rich text control asp.net" for many to choose from.

Comment: Well i need this for windows application

Comment: The winforms rich text box (misread the tag - thought you meant webforms - sorry) will support tables using the standard rtf format. Here's a link to get you started.
http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/17964/0/page/3

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.
What you could do however would be place a rich text field onto the screen and save the content into a .doc format - which you could make available for download or submission.

**EDIT**: question referrred to winforms. This can be done use standard rtf in the rich text box.
link to a tutorial on rtf tables - http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/17964/0/page/3